# How to change the value of a variable before importing a module in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, python-module

Suppose I have a config.py file that has some variables,

```
# config.py
LIFE = 1
MONEY = 200
```

And I will have to import a function which uses those variables within itself,

```
# game.py
from config import LIFE, MONEY

def live():
    if MONEY < 1000:
        print("Money:", MONEY)
        return 'GAME OVER'
    
    else:
        print('Money:', MONEY)
        return 'LIVED ONE DAY'
```

And suppose I went into testing phase, and I have to test the 'game.live' function. But I have no write permissions in either of the game.py or the config.py .  How do you think I could change the value of, say, MONEY variable before calling the 'game.live' function such that the value of MONEY also changes in the 'game.live' function?

For example,

```
# test.py
from config import MONEY, LIFE
MONEY = 20000000000000

from game import live
print(live())

>> Money: 20000000000000
>> LIVED ONE DAY
```

Comment: currently is that the import of your values is done by copy (because they are just integers), you can either change the value at the beginning of your test without impacting the other files that could import it.
Another solution would be to mock these variables, but this is not possible (at least with pytests).
So at the moment, apart from changing the way your code works, it is not possible to do it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change how things work, then its possible to test:

```py
# game.py
import config

def live():
    if config.MONEY < 1000:
        print("Money:", config.MONEY)
        return 'GAME OVER'
    
    else:
        print('Money:', config.MONEY)
        return 'LIVED ONE DAY'
```

Similarly change the test:

```py
# test.py
import config
config.MONEY = 20000000000000

from game import live
print(live())
```

Output as requested

Comment: Still I will be having to change the game.py file, but as the functionality remains the same, it won't be that much of an issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use a database and a file that manages his content.

You can find some examples for python by searching for "sqlite3 example python" it's simple to use.

Good luck with this

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. But as for the smaller projects now, I will be using config.py file as for storing all API keys and passwords.